# Render to named path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber

I have a rails project with the following route:

```
get 'login', to: 'user_sessions#new', as: :login
```

In my `UserSessionsController` I have

```
def create
   @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])

   respond_to do |format|
     if @user_session.save
       # Do all the happy stuff
     else
       format.html { render :action => 'new' }
       format.xml { render xml: @user_session.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end
```

That's working ok, except that when the user enters incorrect parameters the route is via `/user_sessions` instead of `/login`, which is untidy (and means my test assertions are confusing).

Obviously I could just `redirect_to login_path`, but then my `@user_session.errors` don't seem to be available so by page doesn't show what was wrong.

How do I redirect back to `/login` and still have the errors show?

Edit:
It looks as if Rails makes this difficult because it's something I shouldn't try to do. The RESTful path isn't really something the user cares about so I shouldn't be using it as part of my UI testing. Instead, I am looking at the actual content of the rendered page, which the user *does* care about. Thanks all.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. What do you mean with "which is untidy and my assertions are confusing"?

Comment: It means that the user sees two different paths for the same thing and that the simple Gherkin statement `expect(current_url).to eq(login_url)` doesn't work for `Then I should see a login form`; there are two URLs that satisfy the specification. Unless I can fix it, I'll need a more complex step definition.

Comment: `that the user sees two different paths for the same thing` @digitig you are not getting the point. When validation error occurs you are not on new action but on the create action

Comment: I know I'm not getting the point - that's why I have a problem! :)

How do I solve the cucumber/gherkin step definition problem, then? Rather than looking at URLs, should I look for a way of detecting that the partial `user_sessions\_form.html.erb` is being rendered?

Comment: i don't know what you are testing in your step definition so can't say but what you can do is in case of new action you can test for your forms id and since create action doesn't have a template so i don't think you need to test it

Answer (score 3):

You can add

```
post 'login', to: 'user_sessions#create', as: :post_login
```

and change the form action accordingly.

Comment: No I can't, because I then have two conflicting routes for `login`.

Comment: Not exactly, it depends on the HTTP method you're using. A form sends a POST request, so it shall get dispatched to the `create` action. A GET request will be dispatched to the `new` action.

Comment: Well, all I know is that if I add that line, Rails won't run because of conflicting paths.

Comment: Hmmm, then use another path name. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when you *get validation errors in your form then **you are on create action and not new action***. *Your create action simply render your new actions template with errors, **it doesn't send a request to server and hence your url remains same** so to fix it you can simply change the route for your create action* to this:

```
post 'login', to: 'user_sessions#create', as: :login
```

**Update:**

You'll just have to change your route for create action and then make changes in your form, something like this:

```
<%= from_for @resource, url: login_path do |f| %>
  // form fields
<% end %>
```

*If you'll inspect your form **you'll see that its method is POST so when you'll submit it, your form will send a POST request** and when you **hit /login in your browsers address bar it'll send a GET request** so in first case you'll go to create action and in second one you'll go to new action*

Comment: It can't be a matter of simply changing the route, surely? Because when I do, I also have to change my redirections and the render statement to include - I assume - `:action => 'post'`. But when I do that I get a "Missing template user_sessions/post, application/post" when I try to do the rendering. Do I need to create another HTML file for POST? Surely POST shouldn't have a view?

Comment: @digitig you'll just have to change your route for create action and then change your form accordingly so that when you submit your form, your action will receive all the parameters. Updating my answer to include details